# Confused about C# function output

Tags: c#

When I worked through this example in my head I got an output of `4 8 3`. When I run the function however I get the output `4 8 6`, I understand how to get the `4` and the `8` but I can't understand how `y = 6`. Shouldn't `y = 3`? `a1` runs which results in `y +=1` so `y = 1` then `a2` runs which results in `y+=2` so `y = 3`.

```
void Main() {
    int y = 0;
    Func<int,bool> even = (n) => { return n%2 == 0; };
    Func<int,int> dub = (n) => { y += 2; return n + n; };
    Func<int,int> succ = (n) => { y += 1; return n + 1; };

    Func<bool, int, int, int> if1 = (c, t, f) => c? t: f;
    y = 0;
    var a1 = if1(even(3), dub(3), succ(3));
    var a2 = if1(even(4), dub(4), succ(4));

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", a1, a2, y);
}
```

Comment: You have called `dub` and `succ` two time each so the result is 6.

Comment: Dub +2 and Succ +1 and both run twice? 2+1+2+1 = 6

Comment: @JonathanWood n%1 == 0 for all integers. It tells you nothing about whether the number is even. The function given is correct for determining if a value is even.

Comment: But for a1 even(3) returns false so dub does not run but succ does, then for a2 even(4) returns true so dub does run and succ doesn't? Just learning C# so not an expert.

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL C# does not have lazy evaluation. dub() runs before the function if1 is ever called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to realize here is that the two calls to `if1` are passed the *return values* of `dub` and `succ` (because you actually call them).

```
var a1 = if1(even(3), dub(3), succ(3));
var a2 = if1(even(4), dub(4), succ(4));
```

That means that regardless of whether or not the return value is used (as determined by `if1`) the methods have run, and modified `y`. That is why it is 6, as both `dub` and `succ` were called twice by the program, and 2+2+1+1=6

Answer (score 4):

Eventhough you have a conditional expression in `if1` that will only use `t` or `f`, the values send into `if1` are always calculated before the call.

To only calculate the values when needed, you would send in delegates to the function, not values:

```
Func<bool, Func<int>, Func<int>, int> if1 = (c, t, f) => c ? t() : f();
y = 0;
var a1 = if1(even(3), () => dub(3), () => succ(3));
var a2 = if1(even(4), () => dub(4), () => succ(4));
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense.